# c# custom listbox item without word wrap using horizontal scroll

Tags: c#, winforms

So I made a custom listBox in C# windows forms. But it is wrapping the text it holds instead of showing a horizontal scroll bar which is what I want.

The code below is for the listbox:

```
public class MyList : ListBox
{
    public MyList()
    {
        base.ItemHeight = 20;
        base.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        HorizontalScrollbar = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        int index = e.Index;
        if (index < 0 || index >= Items.Count) return;
        var item = Items[index];
        string text = (item == null) ? "(null)" : item.ToString();


            e.DrawBackground();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent), e.Bounds);


        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty certain it has something to do with the `e.Bounds` but I am not sure how to set an "infinite" value and to enable scrolling.

EDIT: In the constructor, I do have `HorizontalScrollbar = true` but it still doesn't show it. Again I think I need to modify the `e.Bounds`

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Figured it out.

You must measure the `string` length of the item the `listbox` holds then compare that to the `listBox.HorizontalExtent` and if it is greater, make that value the new `HorizontalExtent`. For drawing the text without it wrapping, you simply do not pass a width parameter to it. Just a position.

Code:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        int index = e.Index;
        if (index < 0 || index >= listBox1.Items.Count) return;
        var item = listBox1.Items[index];
        string text = (item == null) ? "(null)" : item.ToString();
        int newHE = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.Font).Width + 2);
        if (listBox1.HorizontalExtent < newHE)
        {
            listBox1.HorizontalExtent = newHE;
        }
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, 0f, e.Bounds.Top + 3); //I do +3 because I wanted to shimmy the text down a bit from the top
        }
    }
```